# Calling a method of a class in a while loop in Python only happens once

Tags: python-3.x, class, while-loop

When I call game.play() in the following code, the while loop runs correctly the first time. If the player selects the correct number, then the message is display and the game is ended. If the player guesses the incorrect number, however, the while loop runs infinitely and continues to print either "Your guess is too low...." or "Your guess is too high..."

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
import random

@dataclass
class NumberGuess:
    range: list[int] = field(default_factory=list)
    target: int = 0
    range_beginning: int = None
    range_end: int = None
    user_guess: int = None

    def set_range(self):
        while self.range_beginning is None or self.range_end is None:
            try:
                self.range_beginning = int(input('Enter the first number in the range: '))
                self.range_end = int(input('Enter the last number in the range: '))                
            except ValueError:
                print('Please enter numbers only.')
                self.range_beginning = None
                self.range_end = None

        self.range.append(self.range_beginning)
        self.range.append(self.range_end)

    def randomize(self):
        if self.range_end > self.range_beginning:
            self.target = random.randint(self.range_beginning,self.range_end)
        else:
            self.target = random.randint(self.range_end,self.range_beginning)

    def number_guess(self):
        while self.user_guess is None:
            try:
                self.user_guess = int(input(f'Guess a number between {self.range_beginning} and {self.range_end}: '))
            except ValueError:
                print('Please enter numbers ony.')

@dataclass
class Game:
    winner: bool = False
    num: NumberGuess() = NumberGuess()

    def is_correct(self):
        if self.num.target == self.num.user_guess:
            print(f'You guessed the correct number: {self.num.target}!')
            self.winner = True
        else:
            if self.num.user_guess > self.num.target:
                print('Your guess is too high! Guess again!')
            else:
                print('Your guess is too low! Guess again!')
            self.winner = False

    def play(self):
        self.num.set_range()
        self.num.randomize()
        while self.winner is False:
            self.num.number_guess()
            self.is_correct()

def main() -> None:
    game = Game()
    game.play()
```

I expected that the while loop would call self.num.number_guess() each time it goes through the loop with a new number guess entered by the user each time.

Comment: What is this supposed to do: `num: NumberGuess() = NumberGuess()`? and how is it different than `number_guess()`? None of this seems to be defined in your example.

Comment: It looks like this is a problem with the `number_guess` method.

Comment: I see the issue now. Once the number is set, then self.user_guess is no longer None and the while loop within that method is invalid when it is called again.

Comment: Yep. Why is `user_guess` even an attribute of the `NumberGuess` object though? The value should just be returned directly from the method, and the attribute should be removed.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Good point. I updated it accordingly. And it's it works as expected. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since we can't see your entire code (class NumberGuess),
Here is an example of the supposed expected behavior

```py
import random

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.winner = False
        self.guess = 0
        self.target = 0

    def is_correct(self):
        if self.guess == self.target:
            print(f'You guessed the correct number: {self.target}!')
            self.winner = True
        else:
            if self.guess > self.target:
                print('Your guess is too high! Guess again!')
            else:
                print('Your guess is too low! Guess again!')
            self.winner = False

    def number_guess(self):
        text = input('Guess the number: ')
        self.guess = int(text)

    def randomize(self):
        self.target = random.randint(1,10)
    
    def play(self):
        self.randomize()
        while self.winner == False:
            self.number_guess()
            self.is_correct()

def main() -> None:
    game = Game()
    game.play()

main()
```

(I'm very confused at your syntax)

Answer (score 0):

I see the issue now. Once the number is set, then self.user_guess is no longer None and the while loop within that method is invalid when it is called again. By resetting self.user_guess to None with a wrong answer, then everything works as expected.